# How to fill a rectangle with smaller rectangles of given sizes?

Tags: matrices, tiling, packing-and-covering

I have a problem. I try to find an algorithm to fill up a given rectangle with smaller ones. Something like in this picture:

[image: filling]

I know the size of the big rectangle, the size of all the little rectangles and I know that they fit the big one in one way at least (so I don't have to check if they fit and there might be more correct solutions). I suspect, there is no polynomial algorithm for that, but I did not find any other either. It seems like a pretty basic problem too. Can someone recommend me an algorithm, a paper, or maybe a more well-known problem that is similar, so I can use it as a keyword to find some algorithm that is applicable?

Comment: The decision problem---Can these rectangles pack exactly this given
rectangle?---is NP-hard: [Rectangle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing#Packing_different_rectangles_in_a_given_rectangle). I don't think that knowing the answer is Yes will help you find the packing.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Maybe I did not state it clear enough, but actually, I know that the small rectangles fit the big one.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. And I don't think that helps.

Comment: See this recent blog post: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/10/2d-knapsack-problem.html